# Slow query when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, user_id, cookieId, text_date 
FROM `_history` 
WHERE text_date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-10-01' AND user_id = 1 
GROUP BY cookieId 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cookieId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text_from` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text_body` text NOT NULL,
  `text_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `aName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `hasArrived` enum('0','1') NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `agent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cookieId` (`cookieId`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

An EXPLAN yields this:

```
1   SIMPLE  _history    ref cookieId,user_id    user_id 4   const   49837   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Sometimes the query takes 2 seconds and sometimes its up to 5s.

Any ideas how to make this run faster?

Comment: `group by` without any aggregate function ?

Answer (score 1):

The group by does nothing at the moment so drop it.

The user_id already has an index on it, so the query and sort on it are fine.

The text_date has no index on it, adding an index on it should speed up your query.

If this query occurs often, add a composite index on both user_id and text_date.

eg.

```
create index idx_text_date on `_history` (text_date);
```

Based on the comments, the query should look like this:

```
SELECT cookieId, max(id), max(user_id), max(text_date)
FROM `_history` 
WHERE text_date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-10-01' 
AND user_id = 1 
GROUP BY cookieId 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

And the index should look like this:

```
create index idx__history_text_date_cookieId on `_history` (text_date, cookieId);
```

Comment: I want to group by cookieId to only get unique entries based on cookieId

Comment: Then you should aggregate on the other fields. If you need cookieId in there, as @Barmar answered, you'll need an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite index on `(user_id, cookieId)`.

```
CREATE TABLE `_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cookieId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text_from` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text_body` text NOT NULL,
  `text_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `aName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `hasArrived` enum('0','1') NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `agent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cookieId` (`cookieId`),
  KEY `user_id_X_cookieId` (`user_id`, `cookieId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It will then be able to use the `user_id` index to find the rows, and use the `cookieId` suffix of that index to group them.

When you have this index, you don't need the `user_id` index, because a prefix of a composite index can be used as an index.